# Python BoxCox function yields empty array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, transformation

Trying to learn and use `scipy.boxcox`. But the results of boxcox are simply an empty array instead of a transformed set of data.

I have tried giving BoxCox data in both array, tuple, and list format.

```
import pandas
import psycopg2
import numpy
from scipy import stats

.../...


StarsArray = numpy.array(results)

BoxCoxStars = scipy.stats.boxcox(StarsArray)

BoxCoxResults = scipty.stats.boxcox(results)
```

I start with an array that is (6xxxxxx, 1) and/or a list that is 6xxxxxx. I'm expecting the boxcox transformation to provide a tuple that is 6xxxxxx and/or (6xxxxxx, 1).

Howerver, I get a tuple that simply has the values of: (Numpy array, Numpy array). I get these results when I use either an array or list.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"I start with an array that is (6xxxxxx, 1) [...]"*  In numpy's terminology, that is a *two-dimensional* array.  The second dimension has length 1.  As it says in its [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html), `boxcox` expects the first argument to be one-dimensional; the shape should be (6xxxxxx,).

Comment: *"I get a tuple that simply has the values of: (Numpy array, Numpy array)"*  The [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) explains that, when the arguments `lmbda` and `alpha` are `None`,  there are two return values (called `boxcox` and `maxlog` in the docstring).  So you should *expect* the return value to be a tuple containing these two results.  If `x` is a 1-d array or list, then if you write `y, maxlog = boxcox(x)`, `y` will be the transformed array, and `maxlog` (a scalar) is the value of lambda that was used in the transformation.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser you could have put this as an answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you. How do you make something a one dimensional array?